# How to en/decrypt C# to PHP/Soap client/server communication using AES256

Tags: c#, php, encryption, aes, nusoap

I am trying to encrypt a communication between a C# client and PHP/nuSOAP server using this library: https://github.com/mervick/aes-everywhere/

Everything works as it should when I encrypt then decrypt inside the client/server.

Everything works as it should when when there is no encryption between client/server.

However, when I try to encrypt, send and then decrypt the data I get System.InvalidOperationException: Response is not well-formed XML. How come?

C# code:

```
try
{

    AES spymaster = new AES();
    string key = "admin";
    string encrypted = spymaster.Encrypt(XMLString, key);
    MyOutString = MyServer.test(encrypted);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
}
```

PHP code:

```
     $server->register( 'test', array('$mystring' => 'xsd:instring'),     array('return'=>'xsd:string'), "http://mujserver.cz", false, 'rpc', 'encoded', 'Ignore this description too late oups');


     function test ($mystring) 
     {

             $key = "admin";
             $result = AES256::decrypt($myXMLstring, $key);

             return $result;
     }
```

EDIT: Removed description so not to confuse people.

Comment: Your php code looks like it's converting xml to json

Comment: Yes, that is the intent later on. Right now I am trying to do the encryption/decryption bit. I removed the confusing description.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by converting the data to byte[] first, then sending it!

Relevant functions in C#

```
byte[] System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string);
string System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byte[]);
```

Relevant functions in PHP:

```
string hex2bin ( string $data )
string bin2hex ( string $str )
```

pack(), unpack() would have also worked!